# Rename the Green Llama!

Tags: discussion, status-completed, voting, chat

The official [Puzzling chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/14524/the-green-llama) was named "The Green Llama" a year ago, after a public [contest](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1/name-the-chat-room) where everyone could suggest and vote his favourite name.
It took a year for us to realize that we don't want a green llama in our chat. Why? Try to google "the green llama" and you'll find this insane creature:
[image]

[The Green Thing](http://uncyclopedia.wikia.com/wiki/Green_Thing) is definitely inappropriate for our chat, so we decide to rename it.

**A new contest is open from June 2nd, 2015 until June 9th, 2015.

Rules below:**

- The winner is the name with **most upvotes**. Downvotes won't be considered, we'll only count upvotes!
- You can upvote as many names as you want.
- If you want to add a name to the list, feel free to do it. You can't suggest more than one new name. No profanities, insults, offensive stuff (you know).
- No edits are allowed if you already have upvotes.

*Note: this is also an experiment of [Puzzling polls](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3057/polls-about-puzzling), so please be serious and respect the rules.*

---

## The winner is The Sphinx's Lair (by @Emrakul)

**Final scores (as of June 9th):**

1. **The Sphinx's Lair** (11 votes)
2. The Riddlers' Den (7 votes)
3. Deep Thought (5 votes)
4. The Green Llama (5 votes)
5. Puzzlers' Plaza (5 votes)
6. The Turquoise Tortoise's Voice (3 votes)
7. What's so great about llamas? (3 votes)
8. The Hue Manatee (2 votes)
9. The Mauve Llama (2 votes)
10. The Official Puzzling Chat (1 vote)

Comment: "You can't suggest more than one new name" - in a single answer, or does this mean one user can't suggest more than one new name?

Comment: 1 name = 1 answer. You can't post more than one personal proposal, but you can vote for all the others' names you like.

Comment: "Downvotes won't be considered, we'll only count upvotes!" Clearly people are ignoring this...

Comment: @randal'thor I noticed it, but who cares, we are able to see the UV-DV totals

Comment: @leoll2 People without as much rep as us can't see them! Once the polls have closed, you should probably write all the UV-DV totals into the question.

Comment: @randal'thor I'll do, thanks for the advice.

Comment: I can definitely tell why it's inappropriate.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

## The Sphinx's Lair

I guess nobody liked puce...

Comment: If this one wins, it will be the final nail in the coffin for those who don't like riddles.

Comment: @paco yep i already was reminded of the Riddlers' Den chat room from the old days before the war...

Comment: @d'alar'cop Why not add the Riddlers' Den as a nomination? ;-)))

Answer (score 5):

## The Green Llama

Vote for this if you don't want to change the name.

That Green Thing is pretty cute, no?  ;)

Comment: Cute? After watching https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xe_t_gpr0KI I can't sleep anymore!

Answer (score 4):

## Puzzlers' Plaza

suggested by @pacoverflow (my other answer was not a suggestion, just wanted to give people the option of voting to keep the current name)

Comment: Have an apostrophe mate -> '

Comment: This is a violation of rules!!! Nah, I'm joking... :)

Comment: @d'alar'cop Summon the APOSTROPHE SQUAD!!! At your service, pacoverflow!

Answer (score 3):

## Deep Thought

You can [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_minor_The_Hitchhiker%27s_Guide_to_the_Galaxy_characters#Deep_Thought) its reference.

Comment: Tip: disable the autocomplete when you google "deep th"...

Comment: @leoll2 That says more about you than it does about Google! When I try it, I get "deep thoughts", "deep thesaurus", "deep thinking", "deep thoughts about life", and "deep throat watergate".

Comment: @rand did you know that one's  Google is trained on one's  searches O_o

Comment: @d'alar'cop Yes, but I don't think I'd tried Googling "deep th..." anything before! Why would I need to Google "deep thoughts about life"? I use conversations for that ;-)

Comment: @randal'thor same here.

Answer (score 2):

## The Turquoise Tortoise's Voice

suggested by @leoll2

Comment: I thought it was "The Turquoise Tortoise's Voice"? Or did you change your mind, since it was too hard to spell?

Comment: @mmking It's true, I forgot a piece. Editing the name now would violate my own rules, unless you declare that you're the one who voted this post and would vote "the turquoise tortoise's voice" too.

Comment: Okay. I declare that I voted it, and would not be so mean as to take back my vote just because "'s voice" was appended to the end. Does that work?

Comment: @mmking Seems right. If anyone has objections, I'm ready to withdraw my proposal.

Answer (score 1):

## The Mauve Llama

suggested by @Doorknob

Answer (score 1):

## The Hue Manatee

suggested by @Kevin

Comment: where's the pic?

Comment: @d'alar'cop I prefer not to post pics unless we have one for each proposal. I mean, people tend to vote things with a picture, so I don't want to "manipulate" the poll

Comment: well, for those who do wanna see something funny: http://fc06.deviantart.net/fs71/i/2010/138/2/e/Hue_Manatee_by_Bobert_Rob.jpg (hopefully no one misses the Humanity joke)

Comment: @d'alar'cop I missed the Humanity joke...

Comment: @d'alar'cop ... five years later, I just got the joke. Nothing like a slow burner!

Answer (score 0):

## What's so great about llamas?

suggested by @Bailey M

Answer (score -2):

### The Official Puzzling Chat

Since it is the main chat, why not make it easy to find for new users? We can get creative with all the other chat names, and of course, also in our puzzles and answers.